# In Java 8 why we cannot convert Math.random() to Math::random using method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

This works

```
Supplier<Double> random1 = () -> Math.random();
```

Why this doesn't work:

```
Supplier<Double> random2 = () -> Math::random
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using just the method reference would work such as:

```
Supplier<Double> random2 = Math::random
```

since it already represents a `Supplier<Double>`.

On the other hand, the current notation that you've used would represent a `Supplier` of `Supplier<Double>`  such as:

```
Supplier<Supplier<Double>> random2 = () -> Math::random;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why this doesn't work?
>
> ```
> Supplier<Double> random2 = () -> Math::random
> ```

Because the type `Supplier<Double>` requires function that returns a number, but the lambda returns a function (in this case a method reference) rather than a number.

As Naman points out, this will work:

```
Supplier<Double> random2 = Math::random
```

Notice that there is no lambda in this version.  We are assigning the method reference to `random2`, not a lambda that (when called) returns a method reference.

This is actually a more efficient solution that a lambda that calls the `random` method.  It avoids an extra method call whenever the supplier is used.